# Multi-platform Time and Activity Tracker

Tags: osx, ios, time-management

I'm looking for an app to track time spent on different activities both online and offline. It would work on both, macOS and iOS. On macOS it would automatically track which apps I am using for how long. On iOS it would allow me to start/stop activities that I configure manually (cook, walk the dog, read a book, etc.) 
Ideally the apps would communicate such that the iOS app knows when I'm at the computer and adds those entries automatically.

The app should be lightweight, it's just for personal use, I don't want any extra features for projects, teams, clients, etc.
It doesn't have to be free, but I don't want any service that requires a monthly subscription.

Answer (score 0):

I use an app exactly as described for tracking activity for billing as a freelancer - developer is in Germany, but it reads well in English and has provided excellent tools so far - I use an iPad Pro and Mac, and it coordinates the two beautifully.

https://www.tyme-app.com/

Hope that helps.